# jQuery toggleClass on a table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, hover

I'm trying to highlight a table row when the mouse hovers over it. So I'm using jQuery's `toggleClass()` function. It's worth mentioning that the table rows don't exist initially, they're created after an AJAX call to a server and then inserted into the table. The table rows that get created have a class="table_row". Here's my code ...

```
$('.table_row').hover( function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
});
```

For some reason it won't work, nothing happens. The row won't respond to any events. Here's the code I'm using to create the table elements, and this comes before the above code ...

```
$('tbody').prepend(
    '<tr class="table_row"><td>' + results + '</td></tr>'
});
```

Comment: use delegation for dynamic elements

Comment: Any reason you're preventing the default behavior of the `mouseenter` event?

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
$('tbody').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.table_row', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
});
```

This uses [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to set an event handler for all existing and future `.table_row` elements. `.hover()` binds handlers for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events so this will work the same as `.hover()` would.

You could also consider using the CSS `:hover` pseudo class. However, this might not be what you're looking for if you need to reuse the `.highlighted` class. Here's an example:

```
tbody > tr.table_row{ /* regular styles */}
tbody > tr.table_row:hover{
    // the current styles you have in .highlighted
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try use event delegation, for dynamically created elements. Your hover event is bound only to the element that exists at that point in time, since you are appending them at run time you need to either bind the event again for newly added rows or use eventdelegation to have your container delegate the event to the dynamic rows when available.

```
$('yourtableselector').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.table_row',  function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
});
```

**[event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

`hover` is a virtual event for the combination of `mouseenter/mouseleave`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jZ6Cm/)**

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS instead of JavaScript for simple style changes on a hover event.

```
#my_table > tbody > tr:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

---

But if you did use JavaScript, I'd suggest creating the element, and binding directly to it.

Since hover events happen so frequently as the mouse moves, I'd want to keep the handler as close to the element as possible.

```
$('<tr class="table_row"><td>' + results + '</td></tr>')
    .hover( function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    })
    .appendTo("tbody");
```

Comment: You might want to use `#mytable > tbody > tr:hover` (the `>` probably aren't important) only because they are specifically appending to `tbody`, possibly implying they're distinguishing between it and `thead`. Probably not too important

Comment: I think this is the way to go... +1

Comment: **Very** good point about the events happening so often that you should `keep the handler as close to the element as possible`